# Vpslit - open on the right side of session instead of left?

Tags: window-management

With Vsplit, I always wish the new file would open on the last half of the vim session instead of the first. I can manually do `c-w` and `c-r` to switch them but I would rather have this automatic when I run `vsplit foo.js`.

Any ideas how to make this automatic where the file opens on the right side of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following in your `vimrc`:

```
set splitright
```

Read `:h splitright` for more information.